# Getting IdConvention in RavenDB

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb, ravendb-studio

Lets say we have a User class

```
    public class User
    {
        public User() {
          Created = DateTime.Now;
          Tags = new List<string>();
        }


        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created {get;set;}
        public IEnumerable<string> Tags {get; private set;}    
    }
```

And one might want a user to have an id like [FirstName]/[LastName] so we register an IdConvention like this:

```
     _documentStore
    .Conventions
    .RegisterIdConvention<User>(
      (dbname, commands, user) => user.FirstName +"/" + user.LastName ));
```

Now lets say you created a new user with a new set of tags attached. You want to store it in RavenDB if the User does not exist. However, if the User **does** exist you don't want to overwrite the existing Object as you want to keep the initial `Created` date. Therefore you only update the `Tags` enumeration with the values of the newly created User.

You might do something like this:

```
public void AddOrUpdateUser(User newUser) {
    using (var session = _documentStore.OpenSession())
                {

                    var existingUser = session.Load<User>("myFirstname/myLastname")
                    if(user != null) {
                     existingUser.Tags = user.Tags;
                    }
                   else {

                     session.Store(newUser);
                   }
                 session.SaveChanges();
                }
}
```

However, if for some reason I changed my IdConvention, I have had to update the code above as well. Is there a way to reference the IdConvention registered in order to calculate the id for the `newUser` Object. With this id value you could check wether an item exists or not rather than creating the Id by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After registering an id convention, the `GenerateDocumentKey` method will use that convention instead of the default hilo generation scheme.

It needs some parameters, which are easiest to get at if you first cast the `IDocumentSession` to a real `DocumentSession`.

```
var s = ((DocumentSession) session);
var key = s.Conventions.GenerateDocumentKey(s.DatabaseName,
                                            s.DatabaseCommands,
                                            yourEntity);
```